# Problems with boot after update 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia

Its my second question about same problems, but i haven't fix it. So i have seen some people have same problems with boot. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Yes, I have same black screen after Ubuntu loading. 
I can tell how to deal with it. You have to reinstall Ubuntu, but you shouldn't upgrade it. I tried like ten times to solve the problems, but failed. I think its about nvidia update or what.

Comment: I have read a lot of similar things in forums, and the most, are related to LightDM. Have you lightdm pakacage installed?, if so, please uninstall it, and reboot. Then, installr another Login Manager, like GDM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the conflict between LightDM and Nvidia driver lead to "password loop" after software update (when LightDM was upgraded but driver not)
I uninstalled LightDM, then installed GDM (choosed LightDM as login manager anyway), then uninstalled Nvidia driver and rebooted.
This worked.
To restore screen resolution I had to reinstall Nvidia driver but got probably newer version which didn't conflict with GDM/LightDM.